# Is it possible to use a pointer-to-member to get an actual pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-to-member

I have some struct or class `example`, and I need to send a pointer to any of its members somewhere.

```
void send_ptr(void *ptr, std::size_t size);

struct obj {};

struct example {
    int a;
    obj b;

private:
    static void send_ptr(void *ptr, std::size_t size) {}

public:
    template <typename M>
    void send_member(M *member) {
        send_ptr(member, sizeof(M));
    }
```

This works fine but I thought I could use pointer-to-member here to introduce a little static checking. (The above implementation of `send_member` can actually send an arbitrary pointer.)

```
    template <typename M>
    void send_member(M example::*member) {
        send_ptr(&this->*member, sizeof(M));
    }
};
```

This fails because pointer-to-member dereference (`this->*member`) apparently evaluates to an rvalue.

```
error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
        send_ptr(&this->*member, sizeof(M));
                  ^
```

Now, I thought I could be clever and tried

```
&static_cast<M &>(this->*member)
```

This appears to work but to be honest, I don't fully understand how. Maybe it's unsafe. I know that `static_cast` can be used this way sometimes (like perfect forwarding) but I don't fully understand the semantics here.

So is it possible to use a pointer-to-member to reliably get an actual pointer to the member? Does the `static_cast` work (if so, could you explain how)? Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `&(this->*member)`?

Comment: You might be running into operator precedence issues. Try `&(this->*member)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`operator&` has greater [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `operator->*` and `operator.*`. The `&` will bind to `this` first which is a [prvalue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category), not a [glvalue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) of which you can take the address. Use parentheses to sequence the evaluation:

```
send_ptr(&(this->*member), sizeof(M));
```

Comment: :( Indeed! I thought that I tried this first, actually. I guess not.