# Address of dereferenced pointer

Tags: c++

My question is inspired by [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27724971/is-it-possible-to-use-a-pointer-to-member-to-get-an-actual-pointer).

My understanding of `&(this->*member)` is as follows: the object has a pointer called `member`, that is dereferenced as `this->*member`. We then take the address of what has just been dereferenced. As far as I understand, this should be exactly equivalent to the address of the pointer that was just dereferenced, i.e., exactly the same as `this->member`. Is this not true?

Comment: In `this->*member`, the operator is `->*`. That's one single operator. It's not `->` somehow applied to `*member`. It's not `*(this->member)` either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not, because `member` is not a member.

If you look into the question to which you link, you see that the structure has no member called `member`. Especially it does not contain a pointer called `member`.

`member` is a member pointer, passed as a function call argument.

Comment: If `member` is not a member, then how are you able to use `this->*member`?

Comment: member is a member pointer. In the question you link to, you see that member is not a class member. It is a member pointer, that is, it's the address of a member relative to the containing object. That means `*member`, if it would make sense alone, would be a member. However, since member is a member address relative to an object, dereferencing it makes sense only if the object it known, and then is't used by `->*`.